# Not able to update variable provided during runtime using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I am using webpack to provide variable during runtime into a js file.

```js
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    backgroundVariables: JSON.stringify(backgroundVariables),
  }),
]
```

And changing variable through js file like this.

```js
console.log('background variables', backgroundVariables);
backgroundVariables.captureLogs = true;
```

And it is throwing me this error.

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DefinePlugin` replaces the variable with your code --- it doesn't setup any such variable, so try:

```
let localBackgroundVariables = backgroundVariables;
// essentially the above line is actually replaced by:
// let localBackgroundVariables = {"recordingStatus":...};
console.log('background variables', localBackgroundVariables);
localBackgroundVariables.captureLogs = true;
```

Also I would recommend using more defined variable names in this case, like `process.env.BACKGROUND_VARS` to distinguish it came from `DefinePlugin`.

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.BACKGROUND_VARS': JSON.stringify(backgroundVariables),
  }),
]
```

->

```
let localBackgroundVariables = process.env.BACKGROUND_VARS;
console.log('background variables', localBackgroundVariables);
localBackgroundVariables.captureLogs = true;
```

Comment: The thing is I am providing same variable file to multiple files. Now if i store them in a variable, then the changes wont reflect in other files.

Comment: is there any other way to implement the same thing

Comment: window.localBackgroundVariables = `process.env.BACKGROUND_VARS`
or import them from a "shared library" and instantiate it and pass that global object around